# TMB vs ECL for ELISA: which detection method is more sensitive?

Tags: molecular-biology, antibody, assay-development, elisa

I failed to find a comparison, does anyone know which ELISA detection method is more sensitive of these two: ECL, TMB?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general, ECL is more sensitive than TMB for ELISA detection. The minimum detection limit of TMB is 60pg/mL and 20pg/mL for ultra TMB [[1]](https://info.gbiosciences.com/blog/elisa-substrates-a-selection-guide), whereas the detection limit of ECL can be as low as about 1.7pg/mL  [[2]](https://www.thermofisher.cn/cn/zh/home/life-science/antibodies/immunoassays/elisa-kits/elisa-enzyme-substrates.html).

Resources:

1. https://info.gbiosciences.com/blog/elisa-substrates-a-selection-guide
2. https://www.thermofisher.cn/cn/zh/home/life-science/antibodies/immunoassays/elisa-kits/elisa-enzyme-substrates.html